# SPD Workflow "Call web service" auto retry

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer-workflow

**Environment:**

- SharePoint 2019
- SharePoint Workflow 2013
- SharePoint Designer Workflow
- REST API

I am building a SharePoint Workflow 2013 in SPD. I know there is an auto-retry feature whether the SPD Workflow will automatically retry the request if there isn't a response within 60 seconds.

Does SharePoint retry the request depending on StatusCode? For example if it receives a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR or 400 BAD REQUEST, will it trigger the same retry logic? If yes, can you refer me to the documentation that outlines which status codes trigger this retry logic?

I ask because I have an API that returns `400` or `500` depending on whether the request passes validation. I want to know if I need to change that API to always return `200 OK`.